# Laravel 5 - make https guzzle request with form_param

Tags: php, laravel, curl, request, guzzle

I need to make a POST request to claim voucher. At API docs I find this:

```
POST /vouchers/{voucherId}/claim

{
    "Participant": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Jones",
        "Telephone": "99999 127 127",
        "EmailAddress": "hahahah@hahaha.net",
        "PostCode": "HP18 9HX",
        "HouseNameNumber": "2",
        "Street": "Bridge Road",
        "Locality": "Ickford",
        "Town": "Lodnon",
        "County": "Bucks"
    },
    "ExperienceDate": "2015-10-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Now I, using Laravel guzzle library I make this request:

```
 public function testclaim()
    {

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];

$res = $client->post('https://apidev.asdasd.com/vouchers/11989898_1-9FDD/claim', [
    'headers'=>$headers,
     'auth' => [
        'PET_RES', 'asdasdasd111111'
    ],
    'form_params' => [

        'FirstName' => 'Peter',
        'LastName' => 'Alexo',
        'Telephone' => '8888888888888'

    ]
            ]);
$res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

dd($res);

    }
```

but what I get is:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> { "Message": "The request is invalid.", "ModelState": { "claim": [ "An
>   error has occurred." ] (truncated...)

What is the right way to send a request to the API with following data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
...
'form_params' => [
    'Participant' => [
        'FirstName' => 'Peter',
        'LastName' => 'Alexo',
        'Telephone' => '8888888888888'
    ],
    'ExperienceDate' => '2015-10-01T00:00:00'
]
...
```

if your api just accept json, try replace `form_params` with `json`